# COM: Can't use python comtypes bindings to Thermo Fisher MSFileReader

Tags: python, comtypes

I'm new to COM.  I'm trying to user this python package to read from Thermo Fisher mass spec files.

https://github.com/frallain/MSFileReader-Python-bindings

So I installed Thermo's MSFileReader as instructed:

```
C:\Program Files\Thermo\MSFileReader> ls
Fileio_x64.dll  MSFileReader_Reference.pdf  XRawfile2_x64.dll
```

When I try to use the package, it fails to initialize.  The line that fails is:

```py
import comtypes.client
comtypes.client.CreateObject('MSFileReader.XRawfile')
```

with error

```
OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string
```

I think something needs to go into the registry, but I have no idea how to proceed.  Can someone enlighten me?

Addendum:  Python version

````
3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]```
````

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, but had to back up to installer for this version:

```
MSFileReader_3.0SP3_x86_x64.exe
```

from Francois Allain's github repo.
https://github.com/frallain/MSFileReader-Python-bindings

So, it's apparently a problem with the installer for 3.1SP4.

Hoping to get the most up-to-date version soon directly from Thermo...